# How to use square API in appcelerator-titanium?

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium, appcelerator-mobile, square-connect

I want to make android and iOS application, whitch use square API.
How can i do this using appcelerator titanium?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this Android square module https://github.com/causelabs/Appcelerator-Square-Module

Comment: And what about iOS?

Comment: I don't see an iOS pre-built module. You would have to make one for that to work.